# JSP taglib to select file path - Undefined attribute name type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, taglib

I am trying to create a form. Where the user need to select a file path.

This can be done in html as

```
<input type="file" name="inputFileName"/>
```

If we use html then I don't know how to map that value to "fileObject" class.

So how should I do this with the following code throwing a warning "Undefined attribute name type "

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<body>
<f:form method="PUT" commandName="fileObject" >
<f:input type="file" path="inputFileName"/>
</f:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Exception: 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/Main.jsp(9,0) Attribute type invalid for tag input according to TLD

Comment: What's the problem with `<input type="file" name="inputFileName" />`?

Comment: Mapping of "inputFileName" property of FileObject class will not work.

Comment: did you find solution for your problem.. can you pls share.. i am also looking for solution of above problem

Answer (score 0):

`f:input` does not have attribute type as you can find it in [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input)